# Open new instances of Nemo File Manager in tabs instead of windows

Tags: linux-mint, settings, nemo, dolphin

I'm using Linux Mint 20 and whenever I decompress a zip file it opens the content to a new Nemo window. In Kubuntu when extracting files it opens the content to new Dolphin tabs instead of new Dolphin windows. How can I replicate this behavior in Nemo? I tried to search for an option in Nemo settings but there's none about how to handle this.

Comment: I don't think Nemo can do this - at least I don't see this function in Caja which is based on Nemo but created for Linux Mint MATE. When I run `caja --help` then it has option `--tabs` but it seems doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it seems working in console or in bash with the following syntax :

```shellsession
$ nemo -t "dir1" "dir2" "dir3" &
```

So you could test with folders like these ones, if you have proper user rights, of course :

```shellsession
$ nemo -t "/opt" "/home/$USER/Downloads" "/home/$USER/Videos" &
```

For french people :

```shellsession
$ nemo -t "/opt" "/home/$USER/Téléchargements" "/home/$USER/Vidéos" &
```